# Master slave system with wordpress

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I have set up my wordpress application as follows:-

```
1) One load balancer behind which are two app servers
2) There are two database servers one is master other is slave with master->slave replication set.
```

I want that all the writes to my applicaiton goes to master while read occurs from slave or both.

**How to achieve this in wordpress env ?**

Answer (score 0):

This seems like a REALLY bad idea. Having 2 db's is going to cause more problems than it will solve. That is twice as much code you have to write, and twice as much to maintain. It's hard enough to keep 1 database in order, let alone 2. To top it off, you are going to have to write code to write to one DB, then read from another.

I would avoid this.